# How to print string inside a parentheses in a line in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have lots of lines in a text file. They looks like, for example:

```
562: DEBUG, CIC, Parameter(Auto_Gain_ROI_Size) = 4
711: DEBUG, VSrc, Parameter(Auto_Contrast) = 0
```

I want to exact the string inside the parantheses, for example, output in this case should 
"Auto_Gain_ROI_Size" and "Auto_Contrast".

Notice that, string is always enclosed by "Parameter()". Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "562: DEBUG, CIC, Parameter(Auto_Gain_ROI_Size) = 4"
>>> t = "711: DEBUG, VSrc, Parameter(Auto_Contrast) = 0 "
>>> myreg = re.compile(r'Parameter\((.*?)\)')
>>> print myreg.search(s).group(1)
Auto_Gain_ROI_Size
>>> print myreg.search(t).group(1)
Auto_Contrast
```

Or, without regex (albeit a bit more messier):

```
>>> print s.split('Parameter(')[1].split(')')[0]
Auto_Gain_ROI_Size
>>> print t.split('Parameter(')[1].split(')')[0]
Auto_Contrast
```